# Getting and formatting today and yesterdays date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen this question asked and answered alot, but for some reason I am having trouble.

I am just trying to print out todays date and yesterdays date as mm-dd-yyyy.

**This works without error:**

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

print(today)
print(yesterday)
```

**Output:**

> 2019-08-21
>   2019-08-20

**However, if I try to format it with this, I get an error:**

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

print(today)
print(yesterday)
```

**Error:**

> ```
> .strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The code works for me without an error and the second output is the same as the first one.

Comment: Are you sure you had any errors? or did you run `.strftime` without the `today` or `yesterday`. You might have selected just part of the code

Comment: you need an return `variable = yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`. `strftime` is an function that has return type.

Comment: I am running this all from PyCharm, I wonder if this is causing the issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print out in the format mm-dd-yyyy you just have to do the following:

```
In [1]: from datetime import date, timedelta,datetime
   ...: today = date.today()
   ...: yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

In [2]: print(datetime.strftime(today,'%m-%d-%Y'))
   ...: print(datetime.strftime(yesterday,'%m-%d-%Y'))
08-21-2019
08-20-2019
```

Comment: Well the first issue was my IDE PyCharm - after a relaunch the error went away. After that, I change the print to be similar to yours, and that resolved it. print(today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
print(yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an `strftime` function.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
time = date.today();
time2 = data.today();
time = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y');
print(time); 
// or 
print( time2.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') );
```

Both outputs are:

```
>>'08-21-2019'  
>>'08-21-2019'
```

You can look up more on each function by typing `help(funct)` in console or IDE, where *funct* is function name or syntax to look up. And you can look up all methods for classes and objects by typing `help(obj)`. By typing `dir(obj)` you can have all methods/functions as an list.

A quick check if function returns a value is to just print it out. If function doesn't return value the print function will display `None` into the console, signifying that it didn't get anything from the function.